# Want to show the domain with full page url without shoing the forwarded domain

Tags: php

I'm forwarding a domain to another using IFRAME. so what ever the link is it shows only the domain, not the path. Is it possible to show the path in this case?? I only want to hide the domain on which the site is hosted and want to show the domain which I'm forwarding.

ex: newdomain.com forwarding to olddomain.com
now its showing newdomain.com all time. But I want to show the path of the page after newdomain.com in url

**Update::**
I'm forwarding because when I'm going to change the "A record" in CPanel it telling me that "this needs zoneedit feature & you currently have simplezoneedit feature." In Add an A Record there are 2 text box, Name & Address. In name I'm giving newdomain.com and in address I'm giving the server's address to which I want to redirect.
Do you think I dont have rights to change "A record"?
I also didn't find option to change nameserver in cpanel.

Comment: You need to do this in Javascript. You can use the history API to change the URL in the location bar without redirecting the page.

Comment: I want this. Suppose in newdomain.com , index.php has a IFRAME which have src=oldomain.com. When the IFRAME the src is olddomain.com/about.php then I want to see the page URL as newdomain.php/about.php on the URL bar. & yes I have to forward the new domain to old domain where all the pages hosted.

Comment: @Barmar: No, that won’t work, because the iframe content is from a different domain, so the same origin policy prevents that.

Comment: @CBroe Is it possible by another way if IFRAME not support it?

Comment: _“I'm forwarding a domain to another using IFRAME.”_ – that’s where your whole problem comes from, so just stop doing that, and see to it that the domain points to the new webspace via DNS directly.

Comment: @CBroe yes I know. But when I'm going to change the "A record" in CPanel it telling me that this needs zoneedit feature & I'm using simplezoneedit feature.
In Add an A Record there are 2 text box, Name & Address. In name I'm giving newdomain.com and in address I'm giving the servers address to which I want to redirect

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

This will give you the complete `URL`.

Comment: I want to show this on the URL bar of the explorer. Is it not possible any way?

Comment: you can get the URL But why do you want to show in the URL bar mostly people wants the complete URL to be shown in browser rathen then In URL ..I am not getting you

Answer (score 0):

You can use pushState() method (HTML5 required).

More info on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Example: `window.history.pushState(data, "Title", "new_url.html");`

Comment: As I said in comments already: I don’t think this will work, because the iframe content is from another domain, so the SOP will prevent that.

Comment: You cannot use `history.pushState` across origins. It's a tool for allowing Javascript-heavy sites to avoid reloading, not a way to put inaccurate content into the URL bar.

Comment: if its inaccurate or not doesnt depend on my answer, but on the developer using it. pushState IS a tool to put content into the URL bar. Thats a fact. If its inaccurate or not is another thing.